# Conditional Probability Question : GRE Question

Tags: probability

The coaching staff of a team found that there is a statistical relationship between the weather and chances of victory for their team. For the upcoming match, they found that the probability of success of their team or the weather to be rainy on the same day is 0.25. The local weather channel announced that the probability for rain to occur on that day was 0.2. If historical analysis showed that the probability of their team to win on a rainy day is 0.7, what is the probability that their team wins the next match?

My Approach:
$$ P \left( \text{Raining }\cup \text{ Win}\right) = 0.25 $$
$$ P \left( \text{Raining } \right) = 0.2 $$
$$ P \left( \text{Win} / \text{Raining} \right) = 0.7 $$

where $/$ is used for denoting conditional probability.

$$ P \left( \text{Win} / \text{Raining} \right) = \dfrac{P \left( \text{Raining }\cap \text{ Win}\right)} {P \left( \text{Raining} \right)} $$

$$ P \left( \text{Raining } \cap \text{ Win}\right) = P \left( \text{Win} / \text{Raining} \right) \times P \left( \text{Raining} \right) = 0.14$$

Finally, using summation rule for probabilities we can find

$$ P \left( \text{Raining }\cup \text{ Win}\right) = P \left( \text{Raining} \right) + P \left( \text{Win} \right) - P \left( \text{Raining } \cap \text{ Win}\right)$$

$$ \require{cancel}P \left( \cancel{\text{Raining}}\color{red}{\text{Winning}} \right) = 0.19 $$

Is this correct?

Comment: The more standard notation for conditional probability is just to use `|`, e.g, $P(R|W)$ for the probability of it having rained on a day where they won. It's also simpler if, for instance, you define $R$ as the "it rained that day" event rather than having to use the word over and over again.

Comment: There is a contradiction in your premises.  The problem can not be attacked until the contradiction is resolved.  You have that $$ P \left( \text{Raining }\cup \text{ Win}\right) = 0.25 $$ and $$ P \left( \text{Raining } \right) = 0.4. $$  These premises represent a contradiction.  If you have two events $E_1, E_2$, then you must have that $$p(E_1 \cup E_2) \geq p(E_2).$$  Please edit your posting to resolve this contradiction.

Comment: Re my last comment, I have downvoted your posting because of the contradiction.  After you edit your posting, leave a comment addressed as @user2661923, and I will be flagged.  Then, I will remove the downvote.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you so much for replying. I took this problem from a subscription based GRE preparation service. To learn the concept, I am changing  P(Raining) to 0.2.

Comment: Please send me another flagging comment **after** you edit your posting.  The editing should include your revising all of your work, based on the change in the premise.

Comment: @user2661932 I am really sorry for the comment before making any edits. I have made appropriate changes. Please consider your downvote now. Thanks :)

Comment: You mis-addressed the flagging comment, and you made a labeling mistake at the end of your posting, that I corrected.  Other than that, your analysis is good, and I removed the downvote.